# Which one is default ODS destination in SAS - Listing or HTML?

Tags: sas, sas-ods

Which one is default ODS destination in SAS - Listing or HTML?
In SAS BASE Prep book, it says Listing but in Step by Step SAS programming it says HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the version of SAS, and what you mean by default. There's the user default - which you get when you open SAS, and there's the factory installed default which is what it comes set as in the installation. This is an easily changed option so I wouldn't worry too much about which is default since you can change it in all of the latest versions. I prefer the listing default so I've set my SAS 9.3 to have a listing destination as the default.

I believe in SAS 9.3 the factory default was set to HTML. Prior to SAS 9.3 it was Listing.  So you're possibly looking at books that have refer to different SAS versions.

Comment: Also worth noting that it is not uncommon for SAS to open both listing AND html destinations on launch.  So 'default' is not really a good way to think of it IMO.

Comment: Well, there is a concept of 'default' as in 'on launch' as well as the behavior of the `ods preferences;` statement (which resets to your default).